# Inline CSS with Razor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

Can anyone please answer to me as why this is not working?

For simplistic purposes propose I have the following:

```
var raw = "<div style='background:" + color.HexValue + "'></div>";
```

I am calling it like this:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(raw)</td>
```

And it produces the following:

```
<td><div style=""></div></td>
```

I have tried so many different ways and nothing seems to have worked. Also could you point me in the right direction to how this should be properly done.

Comment: IF you click View Source, do you really see that?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy

```
<td><div style="background: @'color.HexValue'"></div></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background: @color.HexValue;"></div>
```

Comment: @Tyrone: Are you sure, that your color.HexValue isn't null or empty? Because I tried your code and just changed color.HexValue for my own property and it works without problems. So you should check this too.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt response. The string is definitely not null since if I have the following <div>@color.HexValue</div> the value is inserted correctly. Its so strange...

Comment: @Tyrone: if the posted solution isn't working, then you will have to provide more code, because I cant see anything wrong in your code so far. Tested it and its working fine for me.

Comment: this worked for me <td><div style="background: @(color.HexValue)"></div></td>. Leaving out the brackets caused it to display some weird results. Still getting used to razor syntax.

Comment: @Tyroen: Really weird. In my case, it worked only without braces.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating this situation I think. You could write the following in your view and get the right thing:

```
<td><div style="background: @{color.HexValue}"></div></td>
```

Comment: Except that `@{statement}` doesn't output anything. If you're going to surround it it should be `@(statement)`

Comment: My mistake - I didn't bother checking before answering =/

Comment: I will try this... Thank you for your help. Thought I was going crazy!

Comment: This worked brilliantly <td><div style="background: @(color.HexValue)"></div></td>